# Docker image with specific node version

Tags: node.js, docker, version

I'm looking for a way to get a Docker Node image with version v5.10.1 of Node. The official Docker images of Node only are less than 4.8 or greater than 6.0. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As you said, the official Node repo on DockerHub doesn't have an image with version 5.10.1 of Node.

You have to create your own `Dockerfile` or use one unofficial image of DockerHub of Node v5.10.1.

By the way, if you take `Dockerfile` of Node v6.10.0 and change Node version for v5.10.1, you'd have an image of Node almost like the official.

Here is a `Dockerfile` of Node v6.10.0 modified to install Node v.5.10.1. That should solve your problem.

Hope this helps, good luck!

```
FROM buildpack-deps:jessie

RUN groupadd --gid 1000 node \
  && useradd --uid 1000 --gid node --shell /bin/bash --create-home node

# gpg keys listed at https://github.com/nodejs/node#release-team
RUN set -ex \
  && for key in \
    9554F04D7259F04124DE6B476D5A82AC7E37093B \
    94AE36675C464D64BAFA68DD7434390BDBE9B9C5 \
    FD3A5288F042B6850C66B31F09FE44734EB7990E \
    71DCFD284A79C3B38668286BC97EC7A07EDE3FC1 \
    DD8F2338BAE7501E3DD5AC78C273792F7D83545D \
    B9AE9905FFD7803F25714661B63B535A4C206CA9 \
    C4F0DFFF4E8C1A8236409D08E73BC641CC11F4C8 \
    56730D5401028683275BD23C23EFEFE93C4CFFFE \
  ; do \
    gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --keyserver keyserver.pgp.com --recv-keys "$key" ; \
  done

ENV NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL info
ENV NODE_VERSION 5.10.1

RUN curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" \
  && curl -SLO "https://nodejs.org/dist/v$NODE_VERSION/SHASUMS256.txt.asc" \
  && gpg --batch --decrypt --output SHASUMS256.txt SHASUMS256.txt.asc \
  && grep " node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz\$" SHASUMS256.txt | sha256sum -c - \
  && tar -xJf "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" -C /usr/local --strip-components=1 \
  && rm "node-v$NODE_VERSION-linux-x64.tar.xz" SHASUMS256.txt.asc SHASUMS256.txt \
  && ln -s /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/nodejs

ENV YARN_VERSION 0.24.4

RUN set -ex \
  && for key in \
    6A010C5166006599AA17F08146C2130DFD2497F5 \
  ; do \
    gpg --keyserver ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-keys "$key" || \
    gpg --keyserver keyserver.pgp.com --recv-keys "$key" ; \
  done \
  && curl -fSL -o yarn.js "https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/$YARN_VERSION/yarn-legacy-$YARN_VERSION.js" \
  && curl -fSL -o yarn.js.asc "https://yarnpkg.com/downloads/$YARN_VERSION/yarn-legacy-$YARN_VERSION.js.asc" \
  && gpg --batch --verify yarn.js.asc yarn.js \
  && rm yarn.js.asc \
  && mv yarn.js /usr/local/bin/yarn \
  && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/yarn

CMD [ "node" ]
```

Comment: The command '/bin/sh -c set -ex   && for key in     6A010C5166006599AA17F08146C2130DFD2497F5   ; do     gpg

... errors ...

Comment: I think that's due to https://yarnpkg.com is currently down, so `yarn` package cannot be downloaded. Can you access to that website?